# How does SetState() decide whether a widget needs rebuilding?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of state, the `setState` function, and rebuilding stateful widgets. Would this code (inside a method)

```dart
setState(() {
newText="some new text";
});
```

behave any differently from

```dart
newText="some new text";
setState(() {});
```

In other words, does `setState(){}` only concern itself with what's inside itself, or does it pay attention to state changes anywhere inside its parent widget (or even higher than its parent on the widget tree)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setState((){}) rebuilds the current widget state i.e it just calls the build method if you have updated any value inside the setState((){}) or have updated before calling the setState((){}), it will behave same.

For some values which have been initialised or defined inside the build method it will not take any effect, because the setState((){}) just rebuilds the Build() method.

In your case both the setState((){}) calls will behave the same as you have already updated your required value before rebuilding the state. The setState((){}) also updates the values which are dependent on the updated variable from setState((){}) i.e depends upon the variable value which you are updating in setState((){}).

Checkout this [interactivity](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) tutorial by flutter for uses

For the setState((){}) method uses checkout [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)